# T-SQL Case statement where value is derived from joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have the following simple query (sql server 2012)

```
SELECT T.[taskId], T.[sectionId], T.[DateAdded]
FROM [TASK] AS T 
WHERE (T.[deleted] = 0)
ORDER BY T.[DateAdded]
```

What I would like to do is create a computed column called `type`, which will be 1 if `SectionId` is null. If not `null` this will contain a `foreign key` for a `table` called `Organisation`. Organisation has a column called type. If the type of the joined row in organisation is 6 then my computed type value should be 2, else it will be 3.

I'm guessing a `CASE` would be ideal for this but I', not exactly sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To project a derived column, add a join to your organisation table and derive the new column based on the various values:

```
SELECT T.[taskId], T.[sectionId], T.[DateAdded],
   CASE 
      WHEN SectionId IS NULL THEN 1
      WHEN o.[type] = 6 THEN 2
      ELSE 3
   END AS [type]
FROM [TASK] AS T 
   -- Applicable join condition goes here ...
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Organisation o ON t.TaskID = o.TaskID
WHERE (T.[deleted] = 0)
ORDER BY T.[DateAdded]
```

<del>If you **literally** want a computed column, it will look something like this:

    ALTER TABLE TASK ADD [Type] AS 
       CASE 
          WHEN SectionId IS NULL THEN 1
          WHEN (SELECT [type] FROM Organisation WHERE ... JOIN KEY) = 6 THEN 2
          ELSE 3
       END;</del>

Comment: Thats great thanks, I dont want to actually alter the table structure though. Just return this as a computed column

Comment: Apols - I fixated on `COMPUTED` and took it literally :)